# Optimising function for creating adjacency matrices for networks

Tags: r, networking, bioinformatics

I am trying to conduct a network based analysis in R by looking at particular subjects amino acid repertoire.

A connection between one amino acid and another is based on any pair having a Levenshtein distance of 1.

Problem is, the function I have created to output the adjacency matrix that I would need to use for the network diagram is extremely slow and, I would like some advice on how to possibly utilise Rs vectorisation capabilities to do such an operation, or otherwise.

I have read many posts on the forum regarding how slow for loops are in R however, for the purpose of this analysis I simply found no other way to do it.

Here is a snippet of a publicly available dataset, similar to what I'm analysing:

```
structure(list(Gene = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("TRA", "TRB"), class = "factor"), 
    aminos = c("CASSSSMESGNTIYF", "CASSGPGGGAFF", "CASSDSLVRGYQETQYF", 
    "CASSLVENTEAFF", "CASSLQEWDPNYGYTF", "CASSLVENTEAFF", "CASSQEGGTEQFF", 
    "CASSYLGDIQFNQPQHF", "CASSPRTSGGYQEPQYF", "CASSPRTSGGYQETQYF", 
    "CASQHGPGIGTGELFF", "CASSLPDRAGEKLFF", "CASSSGQGNIQYF", "CASSYSVKGLNTEAFF", 
    "CASSWRQGATNYGYTF", "CASSDDVGRLAYEQYF", "CASSEIGRSTGELFF", 
    "CASSFGRQAYEQYF", "CASSAGQGGEHQPQHF", "CASSRSDREMFNYGYTF", 
    "CASSLFSQGWTEAFF", "CASSLYIQGGEQYF", "CASSFGRQAYEQYF", "CASSLENGQYEQYF", 
    "CASSLDKPPPDTGELFF", "CASNQGTATEAFF", "CASSLLLAGGYQETQYF", 
    "CASSYSVKGLNTEAFF", "CASSFEIAGGNEQFF", "CASSHSAGVFMNTEAFF", 
    "CASSLARQEETQYF", "CSATGGRHTGELFF", "CSATRSSGEPEQFF", "CASSQEVAAGGGDTQYF", 
    "CASSLPDRAGEKLFF", "CASSQEMSTGLGEQYF", "CASSQEGSGAPYEQYF", 
    "CASSQEPGAPNTGELFF", "CASSLTVSLSPDLNEQFF", "CASSQDPLAGYTGELFF", 
    "CASSQEPSGGTNTGELFF", "CASSLETGKWGEQYF", "CASSQEGQGAPYEQYF", 
    "CSAGESTPEAFF", "CASSQEASGGPYEQYF", "CASRETGGVWETQYF", "CASSLEGNGHREQYF", 
    "CASSLEGTSGSPDLNEQFF", "CASSLTVSLSPDLNEQFF", "CASSQDPLAGYTGELFF", 
    "CASSQGGDTEAFF", "CASSDLGQGRMNTEAFF", "CASSQEVGTSGEGEQFF", 
    "CASSQEVGQRLLNTGELFF", "CASSQEQGGWGEQYF", "CAVEDTGGFKTIF", 
    "CAASARGQAGTALIF", "CAMREHTSGTYKYIF", "CAENGGNTPLVF", "CAFMITGAGSYQLTF", 
    "CALSVVNQAGTALIF", "CAETGGFKTIF", "CAFMKLESYMDSNYQLIW", "CALSESANSGGYQKVTF", 
    "CALSESANSGGYQKVTF", "CASFPTTSGTYKYIF", "CAVDLTGAGSYQLTF", 
    "CAVEPNSGYALNF", "CAVEPPDGQKLLF", "CAVEPPSGSRLTF", "CAVERSDGQKLLF", 
    "CAVGAGPSGTYKYIF", "CAVQANTNAGKSTF", "CAVSNFMNSGYSTLTF", 
    "CAYRGFYGGATNKLIF", "CAYRSLALIQGAQKLVF", "CAYRSLDLSGNTPLVF", 
    "CAYRSLDVSRDDKIIF", "CAYRTLEGTYKYIF", "CAYRTTLSGGGADGLTF", 
    "CGRTGFQKLVF", "CILSATTSGTYKYIF", "CIVRVPFLYNQGGKLIF", "CLVANGNNRLAF", 
    "CLVARGGSYIPTF", "CLVASPSGGYNKLIF", "CLVEPPPGNGGFKTIF", "CLVGAPLVF", 
    "CLVGDGRGGSQGNLIF", "CLVGDGYGNNRLAF", "CLVGDLTNYQLIW", "CLVGDSGDRGSTLGRLYF", 
    "CLVGDTSSGSARQLTF", "CLVGEAGGFKTIF", "CLVGEAGGFKTIF", "CLVGEGDNYQLIW", 
    "CLVGEGRGGMDSNYQLIW", "CLVGENNNARLMF", "CLVGETNAGKSTF", "CLVGGNNNDMRF", 
    "CLVGGTGTASKLTF", "CLVGPGGFGNEKLTF", "CLVGVPAGNMLTF", "CLVGVPGSARQLTF", 
    "CLVGVPGSARQLTF", "CLVGVPLGGGGNKLTF", "CLVGVPNDYKLSF", "CLVGVYNQGGKLIF", 
    "CLVNTNAGKSTF", "CLVTGSARQLTF")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-110L))
```

Here is the function I have created:

```
getAdjMat4AAs <- function(x){
  SR1 <- x #assignment to input bcause i started this operation on SR1
  net_SR1 <- stringdistmatrix(SR1$aminos, SR1$aminos) 

  colnames(net_SR1) <- SR1$aminos
  rownames(net_SR1) <- SR1$aminos
  #Must find indexes of those w lev dist == 1 out of this huge matrix. Proceed like this.
  ##down there changed from nrow(SR1) -> nrow(net_SR1)
  idx_loc <- matrix(nrow = 2*nrow(net_SR1), ncol = 2) #dont know exact NROW dim of mat, so chose (2x)
  ii <- 1
  for(i in 1:nrow(net_SR1)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(net_SR1)){
      idx <- which(net_SR1[i,j] == 1)
      if(length(idx) == 0){
        next
      }else{
        #idx_loc[[i]] <- paste(i,j, sep = ",")
        idx_loc[ii,c(1,2)] <- c(i,j) 
        ii <- ii+1
      }
    }  
  }

  idx_loc <- idx_loc[complete.cases(idx_loc),] #remove NAs from surplus nrow assignment matrix

  #Also, use unique(AAs) for this calculation, will use rowsums() or colsums() for making centres?
  AAs_col <- colnames(net_SR1)[idx_loc[,2]]
  AAs_row <- rownames(net_SR1)[idx_loc[,1]]

  AAs_colUnq <- AAs_col %>% unique()
  AAs_rowUnq <- AAs_row %>% unique()

  adjMat_SR1 <- matrix(nrow = length(AAs_colUnq), ncol = length(AAs_colUnq))
  #should have the same order of AAs in rows and col for adjacency matrix.. proceed as such
  colnames(adjMat_SR1) <- AAs_colUnq
  rownames(adjMat_SR1) <- AAs_colUnq

  for(i in 1:nrow(adjMat_SR1)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(adjMat_SR1)){
      if(stringdist(rownames(adjMat_SR1)[i], colnames(adjMat_SR1)[j]) == 1){
        adjMat_SR1[i,j] = 1
      }else{
        adjMat_SR1[i,j] = 0
      }
    }
  }
  return(adjMat_SR1)
}
```

Should you run the function on the dataset provided it will not be slow, however, once we are getting into the thousands it becomes extremely slow.

Any advice on optimising this procedure, or even, on the actual method I am using for the network analysis would be much appreciated.

Comment: So far yes, could you point out an error if you found anything that doesn't look right?

Comment: I think you should set `method = "lv"` as an argument while using `stringdistmatrix()` since you want the Levenshtein distance

Comment: Since your code seems to be working correctly (and is only too slow) you might want to consider posting this on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Graipher, next time will do it using code review !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something simple you can do to get the expected adjacency matrix (you can easily wrap it in a function). `SR1` is the data you provided.

```
# define a Levenshtein distance matrix with all the aminos
levenshtein.dist.mat <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(unique(SR1$aminos),
                                                     unique(SR1$aminos),
                                                     useNames = "strings") # I think you should add method = "lv", right ?
# in row are the aminos with a Levenshtein distance of 1 to at least one another amino
levenshtein.dist.mat <- levenshtein.dist.mat[rowSums(sapply(as.data.frame(levenshtein.dist.mat), '==', 1)) > 0, ]
# we can filter the relevant columns
levenshtein.dist.mat <- levenshtein.dist.mat[, colnames(levenshtein.dist.mat) %in% rownames(levenshtein.dist.mat)]
# values not equal to 1 do not represent a connection. Let's set them to zero
levenshtein.dist.mat[levenshtein.dist.mat != 1] <- 0
# output
levenshtein.dist.mat
                  CASSPRTSGGYQEPQYF CASSPRTSGGYQETQYF CASSQEGSGAPYEQYF CASSQEGQGAPYEQYF
CASSPRTSGGYQEPQYF                 0                 1                0                0
CASSPRTSGGYQETQYF                 1                 0                0                0
CASSQEGSGAPYEQYF                  0                 0                0                1
CASSQEGQGAPYEQYF                  0                 0                1                0
```

Comment: Much neater solution! Thank you kindly. And regarding what you said about the "lv" parameter, yes indeed, I will add method = "lv".